# ¿Cómo eliminar el Splashscreen de IONIC 2?

Tags: ionic2

Me gustaría saber si es posible eliminar el extenso tiempo de respuesta en Ionic 2, por ejemplo eliminar el splash screen y la pantalla blanca que aparece al iniciar la aplicación.

Necesito hacer que mi aplicación sea un poco más rápida.

Comment: Supongo que deseas eliminar el Splashscreen de ionic por la dichosa pantalla en blanco. Por lo que te recomiendo echar un vistazo a esta noticia. https://www.digitaldot.es/noticias-informaticas/noticias-desarrollo-web/313-como-acelerar-el-inicio-de-una-app-en-ionic Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes quitar el splash poniendo en tu xml la siguiente linea:

```xml
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

Sin embargo me temo que el tiempo de inicio no será como esperas debido a que la velocidad de inicio es una de las cosas que no se logra con app hibridas, ya que estas al iniciar levantan un navegador y en ella inician tu app, por ello se demora a diferencia de las apps nativas

Answer (score 3):

Con esta línea en confi.xml debería bastar

```xml
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

No se puede reducir el tiempo de respuesta, pero si quieres mantener el  splash screen y quitar la pantalla blanca puedes hacer lo siguiente:

-agregar en el config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

-importar el SplashScreen en 'app.module.ts' la sección de providers:

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [...]
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [...],
      providers: [SplashScreen, ...]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

-agregar en app.component.ts

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(
    public _app: App,
    public _platform: Platform,
    public _SplashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }
```

-en 'initializeApp()'

```
  initializeApp() {
    this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      // do whatever you need to do here.
      setTimeout(() => {
        this._SplashScreen.hide();
      }, 100);
    });
  }
```

Con eso ya no tendrás la pantalla blanca y el splash screen se mantendrá hasta que inicie la aplicación

Comment: una pregunta en esto se deja tal y como esta <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />

Answer (score 0):

Agrega este codigo, para compilar en modo producción

```
// iOS
ionic emulate ios --prod
ionic build ios --prod
ionic run ios --prod
```

// Android

```
ionic emulate android --prod
ionic build android --prod
ionic run android --prod
```

**--prod =  Build the application for production**

Más información acerca de las formas de compilación

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/